# segfault when reading rosbag

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm trying to parse a rosbag file. According to the guide here, I wrote something like this:

```
rosbag::Bag bag;
std::vector<std::string> topics;
std::cout << "Opening " << filename_ << std::endl;
bag.open(filename_.c_str(), rosbag::bagmode::Read);
std::cout << "Mode: " << bag.getMode() << std::endl;

topics.push_back(std::string("/Imu"));
topics.push_back(std::string("/joint_states"));
rosbag::View view(bag, rosbag::TopicQuery(topics));
foreach(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view) {
    std::cout << "Found message of type "  << m.getDataType() << std::endl;
    if(m.getDataType().compare("sensor_msgs/Imu") == 0) {
        sensor_msgs::ImuConstPtr s = m.instantiate<sensor_msgs::Imu>();

        cout << "S = " << s << std::endl;
        double ax = s->linear_acceleration.x;
}
```

The address printed by S is not NULL, but when I reach the last line to get the data, I get a SEGFAULT.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227047/segfault-when-reading-rosbag/) by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2016-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue has been solved by de-referentiating the pointer and using the local variable for data usage:

```
sensor_msgs::ImuConstPtr s = m.instantiate<sensor_msgs::Imu>();
sensor_msgs::Imu imu = (*s);
double ax = imu.linear_acceleration.x;
```

---

Originally posted by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) with karma: 275 on 2016-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0